# iOS 13 - How to detect full screen change?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, safari, ios13

Everything was good and it was possible to detect full screen change via JavaScript. But since iOS 13 I have issue in Safari and Chrome. How to detect full screen change? Thanks

Something like this does not work anymore.

["fullscreenchange", "webkitfullscreenchange", "mozfullscreenchange", "msfullscreenchange"].forEach( eventType => document.addEventListener(eventType, yourCheckFunction) );

Comment: Show us the technique you were using that worked.

Comment: ["fullscreenchange", "webkitfullscreenchange", "mozfullscreenchange", "msfullscreenchange"].forEach(
    eventType => document.addEventListener(eventType, yourCheckFunction)
);

Comment: But these events don’t fired in iOS 13 Safari/Chrome. Any idea?